# Matlab Cell Counting from Image - Background Pollution

Tags: matlab, image-processing, counting

I've been dealing with this problem for days now and I've tried every hit on the first 3 pages of Google for my problem.

I want to count the number of cells in an image. It's been asked before, I know that. But in the lab that I'm in for my summer internship, sometimes the background becomes polluted with light (ideally it's suppose to be in a dark room but it cannot always be guaranteed).

As a result, here are 3 image examples that I am dealing with:

[Link to the Imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sVKX.jpg)

I had to convert them from a TIF to JPEG so the quality might be slightly reduced

I think we can clearly see that there are cells. Each green circle is a nucleus, but it is virtually indistinguishable from the background green pollution.

Again, I've tried all different cell counting methods, and I would include them but including this one (in addition to many more, but Stackoverflow won't let me post more than 2 links):
http://blog.pedro.si/2014/04/basic-cell-segmentation-in-matlab.html

However, I don't know enough about image analysis to determine how to alter those codes to fit my problem.

Any help would be so much appreciated!

EDIT: any help, especially with the nuclei that are identifiable to the naked eye, would be great. I know it gets hard to see some of them. That is because they turn 'green' when they die. and get more green for a few hours after death. Different cells are just at different walks of life